# Getting same thread id inside celery workers

Tags: django, multithreading, celery, celery-task

I tried getting the current thread id and process id while running a task inside a celery worker process. 
I have set prefetch multiplier to 1 and I have 4 cpu core machine, so there will be 4 worker processes running for each workers.
I have only 1 worker running ( 4 worker processes).

As per my understanding each of the worker processes actually handles the execution of task. When I run 4 tasks simultaneously I tried getting the process id and thread id inside the task using os.getpid() and threading.get_ident() respectively.

To no surprise, for every task running I got the same set of 4 process_id (as there are 4 worker processes running), but the thread id for each of the process are same. I am not able to understand how is this possible.

Following is my observations when running tasks:

```
>     log: pid id: 513, t_id 140373758563328
>     log: pid id: 514, t_id 140373758563328
>     log: pid id: 513, t_id 140373758563328
>     log: pid id: 513, t_id 140373758563328
>     log: pid id: 513, t_id 140373758563328
>     log: pid id: 513, t_id 140373758563328
>     log: pid id: 578, t_id 140280371217408
>     log: pid id: 579, t_id 140280371217408
```

Comment: How are you running celery? Prefork/gevent?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am running prefork pool

Comment: Paste the celery command your are running?

Comment: @sp1rs celery -A project.celery worker -l DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much possible that the same worker process picks several successive tasks, especially if it executes tasks faster than you are sending. If you prefer a more random behaviour, pass the `-Ofair` optimisation parameter to your workers (something like: `celery -A my.project.app worker -c 5 -O fair -l info`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not the case, as I'm getting different process id every time I run a task (these process ids that I get are always subset of 4 process ids, as there are 4 worker processes running). But the thread id are always the same, I have also tried the - 0 fair option, still I am getting the same thread ids.

Comment: What is your concurrency type? prefork? eventlet? gevent? thread?

Comment: It is the default one - prefork. I started my worker using the following command: celery -A project.celery worker -l DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

The thread if fro the [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) library is probably not the correct way to get a Celery worker's thread id. That's because Celery uses different libraries for concurrency and it depends on your configuration. By default these pools of workers are managed by [billiard](https://billiard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (also a Celery project library) and the correct way to get the process info would be to use [current_process](https://billiard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=current_process#multiprocessing.current_process)